# In Spanner what is the equivalent to MySQL wait_timeout and connect_timeout variables?

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp, google-cloud-spanner

In mysql you can check this variables with commands like:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'connect%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_%';
```

in spanner how can one check this and also edit them?

I need to know because I am getting this warning in SpringBoot with Hikari:

[Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value - hikari connection pool spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310858/possibly-consider-using-a-shorter-maxlifetime-value-hikari-connection-pool-spr)

I have seen it before, with mysql you set this hikari property based on the wait_timeout configured on the database, but with spanner im not sure, I am using default hikari config so it is set on 30 mins by default.

Edit (screenshot of hikari warning):

[image: warning]

Comment: I couldn't find anything for query. But, You can refer these documents for setting connection and wait timeout: [document1](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/samples/cloud-sql-mysql-mysql-timeout) & [document2](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/custom-timeout-and-retry)

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Most Cloud Spanner clients do not support connection variables, because many of the clients are stateless. The Cloud Spanner JDBC driver does support a fixed set of connection variables. These are documented here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/jdbc-session-mgmt-commands

Comment: I am getting a warning about using a shorter maxLifeTime for my connections, with Hikari https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310858/possibly-consider-using-a-shorter-maxlifetime-value-hikari-connection-pool-spr to the spanner database, I have seen this before when using mysql so based on the database config I setup this variable for hikari to anticipate when a connection is no longer reusable, but with spanner im not sure where to check the wait_connection property of the database, I am using default config so Hikari keeps maxLifeTime as 30 mins

Comment: The Cloud Spanner JDBC driver internally makes sure to keep all underlying connections alive. Are you seeing any warnings / problems when using the Cloud Spanner JDBC driver with Hikari? Or is it more of a precaution? In the latter case, I would say that you do not need to change anything.

Comment: I added an edit to my question, added the warning I am getting spammed in the logs some times

Comment: The `Pool has been closed` error indicates that the internal session pool of the Cloud Spanner JDBC driver has been closed. Are you getting this error when shutting down the application?